# The miraculous identity?

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Closed” form for $\sum \frac{1}{n^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/closed-form-for-sum-frac1nn)

One of the problems on the tryout exam for my university's Putnam team was to prove the following:

$$\int_0^1x^xdx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}n^{-n}$$

I was elated when I saw this, because I knew I had seen a proof somewhere; unfortunately, I completely failed to remember the proof, and thus afterward wanted to look it up.  I then ran into the other problem that I don't remember the name of the identity, if it has a standard one (I remember a Wikipedia page calling it something like the "marvelous identity" or the "miraculous identity").

Thus, I'm really looking for two things- the name of this identity, if there is a standard one, and a proof of it.

Comment: [Sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream)

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/closed-form-for-sum-frac1nn) and [on AOPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=354567&sid=392d6f2d324594580af0ce01ba344d29#p354567)