# Sum of reciprocals of powers

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Closed” form for $\sum \frac{1}{n^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/closed-form-for-sum-frac1nn)

Using Weierstrass theorem (any monotonic and bounded sequence is convergent), we can prove that the sequence $u_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^k}$ with $n$ a positive integer is convergent. But can we actually find its limit ?

Comment: There is no known closed form expression.  Although there are series related to it which have closed forms.  Since $k!\approx e^{-k}k^k\sqrt{2\pi k}$, we can look at things like $\frac{k^k}{k!e^k}$.  One such limit is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\right)=-\frac{2}{3}-\frac{\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.$$

Comment: [A related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330) If we're hard pressed to find a tidy expression for the infinite sum, I don't see how finding an expression for the finite version is any easier.

Comment: Actually, I think this is a duplicate of 21330. Ismail writes "the sequence $u_n$ ... is convergent. But can we actually find its limit?" This seems to me to be asking abut the infinite sum, which is the subject of question 21330.

Answer (score 3):

There is the famous [sophmore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) identity:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^k} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

"Find" in the sense of "having a closed form expression"? Likely, no, under most reasonable interpretations of "closed form expression". One can of course calculate the limit approximately (it is roughly 1.2913...) - this is pretty easy since the series converges very fast.