# Indefinite integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to solve $\int x^xdx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141347/how-to-solve-int-xxdx)

Indefinite integral $$\int x^x dx $$ knowing that $$x^x=e^{x \ln x}$$ and then using method of partial integration recursively I can get an infinite series. Does exist a closed form of this integral expressed in terms of elementary functions. I am interested also where appear this sort of integral.

Answer (score 0):

The closed form for this integral doesn't exist. For proof, this would surely help: [Proof that $\int x^x dx$ can't be done in terms of elementary functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107870/proof-that-int-xx-dx-cant-be-done-in-terms-of-elementary-functions)