# What's the sum of $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{k}}{k^{k}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Absolute convergence and uniform convergence are easy to determine for this power series. However, it is nontrivial to calculate the sum of $\large\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{k}}{k^{k}}$.

Comment: According to Wolfram alpha, there is no closed form, not even for $t = 1$.

Comment: Using Stirling's approximation, $k^k\approx e^k k!$, so it looks like this sum should go approximately like $\exp(t/e)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's define : $\displaystyle f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{k}}{k^{k}} $

then as a [sophomore's dream](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SophomoresDream.html) we have : $\displaystyle f(1)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{k^{k}}=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^x}$
(see Havil's nice book ['Gamma'](http://books.google.fr/books?id=7-sDtIy8MNIC&pg=PA44) for a proof)
I fear that no 'closed form' are known for these series (nor integral).

Concerning an asymptotic expression for $t \to \infty$ you may (as explained by  Ben Crowell) use [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $k!\sim \sqrt{2\pi k}\ (\frac ke)^k$ to get :

$$ f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^k}{k^k} \sim \sqrt{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{k}(\frac te)^k}{k!}\sim \sqrt{2\pi t}\ e^{\frac te-\frac 12}\ \ \text{as}\ t\to \infty$$

EDIT: $t$ was missing in the square root

---

Searching more terms (as $t\to \infty$) I got :

$$ f(t)= \sqrt{2\pi t}\ e^{\frac te-\frac 12}\left[1-\frac 1{24}\left(\frac et\right)-\frac{23}{1152}\left(\frac et\right)^ 2-O\left(\left(\frac e{t}\right)^3\right)\right]$$

But in 2001 David W. Cantrell proposed following [asymptotic expansion for gamma function](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=342644&tstart=0) (see too [here](http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math.num-analysis/msg/521fa1a6fb98a300) and the [1964 work from Lanczos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation)) : 
$$\Gamma(x)=\sqrt{2\pi}\left(\frac{x-\frac 12}e\right)^{x-\frac 12}\left[1-\frac 1{24x}-\frac{23}{1152x^2}-\frac{2957}{414720x^3}-\cdots\right]$$

so that we'll compute :
$$\frac{f(t)}{\Gamma\left(\frac te\right)}\sim \sqrt{t}\left(\frac {e^2}{\frac te-\frac 12}\right)^{\frac te-\frac 12}$$

and another approximation of $f(t)$ is :
$$f(t)\sim \sqrt{t}{\Gamma\left(\frac te\right)}\left(\frac {e^2}{\frac te-\frac 12}\right)^{\frac te-\frac 12}$$

Comment: [Related sum](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/205896).

Answer (score 7):

I asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/closed-form-for-sum-frac1nn). That question led Owen and me to the function you asked and we wrote up some nice (an incomplete version) properties [here](http://www.stanford.edu/~sivaambi/Upsilon_Function.pdf). To give a short answer to your question, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k^k} = t \int_0^{1} x^{-tx}dx$$

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to the integral

$$\int_0^1 (tx)^x dx$$

Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/closed-form-for-sum-frac1nn) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)

I don't have time to work it out now, but I'll edit in a while.

---

I've checked and as Sivaram points out, the integral is actually

$$t\int_0^1 x^{-tx} dx$$

Comment: Holy cow, the ending of the episode... I mean, I knew where it's going, but still. Wow.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's 1:32 a.m. Should've gone to sleep almost 3hs ago. I am going to take up drinking. I hate George Martin.

Comment: If you'd read all the spoilers/the books, you wouldn't be surprised. You'd be amazed at the graphical description of the fight.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I actually read the complete scene from the book when I finished, though I never read the book!

Comment: Hah, yeah, me too. I liked the TV adaptation better.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The quality of the show has been increasing, methinks. Still not over the Viper being gone =(. Loved his character.