# What's the sum of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{kx}}{e^{k^2}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I already asked a similar question on another post:
[What's the sum of $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{k}}{k^{k}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115410/whats-the-sum-of-sum-limits-k-1-infty-fractkkk)
There are no problems with establishing a convergence for this power series:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{kx}}{e^{k^2}}$$
but I have problems in determining its sum.

Comment: I don't think this will be any less intractable...

Comment: Substitute $t=2^x$, consider $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{t^k}{e^{k^2}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this Jacobi theta function:
$$
\vartheta_3 \biggl(\frac{i}{2} x \operatorname{ln} (2),\operatorname{e} ^{-1}\biggr) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{e} ^{-k^{2}} 2^{k x}
$$
But you stopped half-way through, so yours is not such a common one.  Yours is a "partial theta function"

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{kx}}{e^{k^{2}}} = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \prod_{m=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{e^{2m}} \right) \left( 1+ \frac{ 2^x }{e^{2m-1} } \right) \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2^x e^{2m-1} }\right ). $$

Comment: out of the frying pan into the fire

Comment: @Norbert haha yea pretty much =] But the OP wanted *something*, so there it is.

Comment: @Ragib: By what method did you find this?  Just a name or reference please.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Google "Jacobi Triple Product".

Comment: @Ragib: Thanks!