# series look up site

Tags: power-series

Is there a site for looking up a series to see some of the associated functions. (In the spirit of Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences [OEIS](https://oeis.org).)
In particular I am looking for functions related to $ \sum (x/n)^n$.

Comment: Related is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115410/whats-the-sum-of-sum-limits-k-1-infty-fractkkk) as well as the many links in the answers and the comments there.