# Definite integral of tetration between $0$ and $1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, power-series, tetration

In my old writes I've found the following formula, where ${_{}^2}x$ is [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration):

$$\int_0^1 {_{}^2}x \ dx = \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{i+1}} {{_{}^2}i} \approx 0.783430511\ldots$$

Now I am interested in series of generalized case of tetration:

$$\int_0^1 {_{}^n}x \ dx = ?$$

Could anybody find out it with an explanation?

Comment: FYI, the formula is explained in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream.

Comment: I just proved a generalization of the Sophomore's Dream for [equation $(2)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205860/the-sum-of-a-series/205896#205896). Sophomore's Dream, as cited above, uses $q=-1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $x>0$ and

$$a_{n,k}=
  \begin{cases}
    1 & \quad \text{if $k=0$}\\
    \dfrac{1}{k!} & \quad \text{if $n=1$}\\
    \displaystyle \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k ja_{n,k-j}a_{n-1,j-1} & \quad \text{otherwise.}\\
  \end{cases}
$$

Then

$$
\int {}^n x\, dx=
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k (k+1)^{k-1}\Gamma(k+1, -\log x)}{k!} + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (-1)^k a_{n,k} \Gamma(k+1, -\log x) + C.
$$

Source: [I.N. Galidakis, *On an Application of Lambert’s W Function to Infinite Exponentials*](http://www.math.usm.edu/lee/InfiniteExponentials.pdf), Corollary 10.9.

Comment: It's great, but what ablout case of definite integral inside of $[0; 1]$ interval?

Comment: @KvanTTT Find $F(b)-F(a)$?