# Solving $x^{x^x}=c$ with Lambert's W function

Tags: exponential-function, special-functions, lambert-w

We can solve the equation $x^x=c$ using the *Lambert* $W$ *function*, but how do we solve $x^{x^x}=c$?

Comment: precalculus???? ;-)

Comment: tagged By mistake, fixed

Comment: @tired I do not totally disagree with this tag. After all, if $W$-Lambert function were taught in high school, simply as the inverse of $f(x)=xe^x$, it would be only a "difficult logarithm". It is still somewhat confusing, though.

Comment: With Lambertson's $W_w$ function ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Simply search "Lambert W function"

Comment: @Aditya You're responding to ajotatxe, not Yves. Both know what the Lambert W function is. ajotatxe was asking Yves about the "$W_w$" function in their comment, which is a joke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a solution, but you can solve a similar equation with a double application of $W$:

$$x^{x^{x+1}}=c,$$

because

$$x^{x^{x+1}}=(x^x)^{x^x}.$$

Unfortunately, $x^{x^{x+1}}$ is far form $x^{x^x}$, as it is $(x^{x^x})^x$.

---

For a numerical solution, I recommend Newton, with the iterations

$$x\leftarrow x-\frac{x\ln x+\ln \ln x-\ln\ln c}{\ln x+1-\dfrac1{x\ln x}}.$$

For the case $x^{x^x}=500$ with the starting approximation $2.3$, in three steps,

$$\begin{align}2.3&\to 286.234283705\\
2.33993454643&\to 499.860587996\\
2.33995361844&\to 499.999999977\\
2.33995361844&\to 500.0\end{align}$$

---

An initial value can be estimated empirically by dropping the second term in

$$x\ln x+\ln\ln x=\ln\ln c.$$

Then solving with Lambert and using one of its [asymptotic expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions) we get

$$x\approx\frac{\ln\ln c}{\ln\ln\ln c}(\ln\ln\ln c)^{1/k \ln\ln\ln c}.$$

By trial and error, we found $k=4$ to give good results (e.g. $500\to2.457$) for values of $c$ in the range of double-precision floats. It is worth to note that because of some overshoot, with this starting formula Newton's iterations fail on the evaluation of $\ln\ln x$ for $c<33$. Smaller values require a different method.

Answer (score 5):

Taking a part of Yves Daoust's answer, see that

$$x^{x^{x+1}}=(x^x)^{x^x}=\left(x^{x^x}\right)^x=c$$

can be solved with two applications of the Lambert W function.

But of course, you wish to find $x^{x^x}=c$.

Suppose you know $x\approx d$.

This means

$$d^{d^d}\approx c$$

$$\implies d^{d^{d+1}}\approx c^d$$

Or,

$$x_{n+1}^{x_{n+1}^{x_{n+1}+1}}=c^{x_n}$$

$$\large x_{n+1}=e^{W\left[W(x_n\ln(c))\right]}$$

So, if you have a calculator handy, you can do something along these lines:

$$x_0=d$$

$$x_1=e^{W\left[W(d\ln(c))\right]}$$

$$x_2=e^{W\left[W(x_1\ln(c))\right]}$$

$$etc.$$

Testing it with $c=500$ and $x_0=2.3$:

$$\begin{align}
x_0 & =\overline{2.3} \\
x_1 & =\overline{2.33}3760625 \\
x_2 & =\overline{2.339}000432 \\
x_3 & =\overline{2.3398}0707 \\
x_4 & =\overline{2.3399}31091 \\
x_5 & =\overline{2.33995}0156 \\
x_6 & =\overline{2.339953}086 \\
x_7 & =\overline{2.3399535}36 \\
\end{align}$$

See that $x_7^{x_7^{x_7}}=499.9994005$.  The calculations may be a little off because I did them with my scientific calculator though, but it seems accurate enough.  It also seems that it approximates one more digit at a time correctly, which may seem slow, but given the size of the numbers we are trying to use, a few digits make good differences.  (compare $x=2.3$ and $x=2.4$ and see how far they are off from $c=500$.)

Also note that for the most part, the solution will be less than $4$ if $c$ even fits on your calculator.

Comment: Nice approximation.

Comment: @Pentapolis Thanks.  I use fixed-point iteration for the calculation of the Lambert W function.  Comes in handy for these weird type problems.

Comment: @SimpleArt, clever solution. I tried "solve x^x^x=500" in Wolfram Alpha and got $x \approx 2.33995361843844...$ with no work shown and "Standard computation time exceeded..." message. This seems to indicate no solution even in terms of exotic special functions. If someone has access to Mathematica it would be interesting to learn what they obtain.

Comment: @poweierstrass Yeah, I'm limited to scientific calculators and slower fingers than Mathematica.  Something like Mathematica would be great.

Comment: If you go for a numerical solution, Newton will do a much better job than this fixed-point approach, which in addition requires two $W$ evaluations per iteration. And how do you get $d$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust You guess, like you do at the start of most numerical algorithms.  And yes, Newton's method would probably do better, but I decided to go with simpler Fixed-point.

Comment: @SimpleArt: you can do better than guessing. And I wouldn't call "simpler" nested fixed-point iterations.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sure.  :3 sorry I can't upvote you because I only get one upvote per answer.

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution can be extrapolated from my first question on this site (found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1438567/269764)), where I explain that the function 
$$x^{x^x} = \,^3x = x + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\bigg(\frac{S_{n-1}^{k+1}\log^{k+n}(x)x^n}{\Gamma(n)}\bigg) = x + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\bigg(\frac{S_{n+1}^{k+1}\log^{k+n+2}(x)x^{n+2}}{\Gamma(n+2)}\bigg)$$
Where $S_n^k$ are the Stirling numbers of the second kind. This could potentially be used to express a solution in terms of an infinite series which could then be calculated to arbitrary accuracy.

Comment: The idea of pulling the solution out of the sum is not a pleasant one.  How would you approach that?

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ with $f(x)=x^{x^x}$ doesn't have [partial inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) over non-disrete domains in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) and/or Lambert W. Therefore, your equation $x^{x^x}=c$ cannot be rearranged for $x$ by applying only Lambert W and/or elementary operations (means elementary functions) you can read from the equation.
But it is an open question if the equation has solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

Equations of your kind can be solved by generalized Hyper Lambert W functions (see the references below).

$$x^{x^x}=c$$
$$e^{\ln(x)e^{\ln(x)x}}=c$$
$$\ln(e^{\ln(x)e^{\ln(x)x)}}=\ln(c)$$
for $-\pi<\Im(\ln(x)e^{\ln(x)x)})\le\pi$:
$$\ln(x)e^{\ln(x)x}=\ln(c)$$
$$G(\ln(x);\ln(x))=\ln(c)$$
$$\ln(x)=HW(\ln(x);\ln(c))$$
$$x=e^{HW(\ln(x);\ln(c))}$$

So we have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $x$, and the series representations of Hyper Lambert W (e.g. [Lagrange inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem)) give some hints for calculating $x$.
$\ $

[Fantini, J.; Kloepfer, G.: Wexzal/The coupled Exponent, 1998](http://eretrandre.org/rb/files/JayFantini1998_203.pdf)

[Helms, G.: Wexzal"/"coupled exponent" , "Superroot" and a generalized Lambert-W](http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/Wexzal_Superroot.pdf)

[Galidakis, I. N.: On solving the p-th complex auxiliary equation $f^{(p)}(z)=z$. Complex Variables 50 (2005) (13) 977-997](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233129552_On_solving_the_p-th_complex_auxiliary_equation_fpzz)

[Galidakis, I. N.: On some applications of the generalized hyper-Lambert functions. Complex Variables and Elliptic Equations 52 (2007) (12) 1101-1119](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233200491_On_some_applications_of_the_generalized_hyper-Lambert_functions)

[Galidakis, I.; Weisstein, E. W.: Power Tower. Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html)