# Solving tetration equation with Lambert W Function

Tags: lambert-w

> Does anyone know how to use the Lambert W Function to solve the equation
>   $$x^{x^x}=2$$
>   for $x$?

I've figured out how to solve these two similar equations:
$$x^x=2$$
$$x^{x^{x+1}}=2$$

Comment: Do you have any reason to think LambertW will solve this?  I don't.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Lambert W solves the two similar equations on the bottom, so I thought perhaps it could be used for the above one.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937521/solving-xxx-c-with-lamberts-w-function)

Answer (score 0):

We can use Newton's method to approximate the answer

$x^{x^x}=2 \implies x^{x^x}-2=0 $

Let $f(x)=x^{x^x}$ after a lot of work we get that $f'(x)=x^x\times x^{x^x} \times ({1\over x} + \log x +\log^2x)$

Now let's pick a starting value

$x_1=1$ Then every next value would be of the form $x_{n+1
}=x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$

then $x_2=2$

$x_3 \approx 1.72256 $

$x_4 \approx 1.58439 $

$x_5 \approx 1.72256 $

...

at around $x_{10} 
$ it converges to $1.4766843374$

Turns out it is a really good approximation too! As $1.4766843374^{1.4766843374^{1.4766843374}}=2.0000000001826366$

Not really what you probably expected , I am still not sure if this is solvable using the Lambert W function but I am pretty sure it is not .