# $x^{x^{x}}=2$ : How can I solve this exactly?

Tags: lambert-w

I solved the following equation today for fun and I have the exact real result:

$x^{x^{x+1}}=2 \Leftrightarrow x=\frac{W(ln(2))}{W(W(ln(2)))}=\exp ^{W(W(ln(2)))}$

Where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

But how can I now solve $x^{x^{x}}=2$ exactly? I know it's another similar question, but I just love exact results from such cool equations. Thanks for answers!

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2611525/solving-tetration-equation-with-lambert-w-function?noredirect=1).

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291993/since-xxx-is-one-to-one-on-the-interval-0-infty-solve-for-x-if-x/3555197#3555197) has an integral representation for the constant

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think so. It's just sad that you can't express it exactly in general, so as a result