# solving for exact solution of $x^{x^x} = 17$

Tags: exponential-function, closed-form, lambert-w

Im trying to solve for the exact solution of

$$
x^{x^x} = 17
$$

I understand that the previous solution, $x^x=17$, does not have an exact closed form solution and requires use of the Lambert W function, however i have not found an answer (from wolfram included) that seems to provide a non approximated answer even without said constraints. When approximating, however, the final answer appears to be close to $2.009$.

Does anyone know of a closed-form solution to this problem, be it even if it involves use of non-elementary functions?

Comment: It can be shown that the function $F(x):=x^{x^x}$ is strictly increasing on $[1,\infty)$ and that $F(1)=1$. Then, there exists a unique function $F^{-1}:[1,\infty)\mapsto[1,\infty)$ such that $F^{-1}\circ F=\mathrm{Id}$. The exact solution is then $F^{-1}(17)$ and $F^{-1}$ is non-elementary.

Comment: Just for the fun $x=2+\frac{1}{100} \left(\frac{1}{3}+\cos (1)\right)^{\frac{1}{4}
   \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)}$ gives $16.999999822$

Comment: Why bother about a possible exact solution , if we can easily determine the solution with arbitary precision ? Even for theoretical purposes, such an expression would be neither useful nor enlightning. Interesting, but probably out of reach would be a proof that the solution is transcendental (already an irrationality proof would be interesting).

Answer (score 2):

If you want a definition of the exact value, consider that it is the limit, when $n\to \infty$, of the first iterate of a Newton-type method of order $n$.

Thsi will give for example, with $L=\log(2)$
$$x_{(2)}=\frac{65+128 L+128 L^2}{32+64 L+64 L^2}$$
$$x_{(3)}=\frac{274+1084 L+2136 L^2+2120 L^3+1056 L^4}{135+538 L+1064 L^2+1060 L^3+528 L^4}$$
$$x_{(4)}=\frac{ 27735+164754 L+487008 L^2+855140 L^3+951704 L^4+630240 L^5+209024
   L^6 } {13665+81570 L+241908 L^2+425980 L^3+475060 L^4+315120 L^5+104512
   L^6 } $$

The first decimal values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_{(n)} \\
 2 &      \color{red}{2.00}93361604829833 \\
 3 &      \color{red}{2.00896}17010469369 \\
 4 &      \color{red}{2.0089646}624948464 \\
 5 &      \color{red}{2.0089646909}446277 \\
 6 &      \color{red}{2.0089646909}923880 \\
 7 &      \color{red}{2.008964690988}6512 \\
 8 &      \color{red}{2.00896469098858}31 \\ 
\cdots & \cdots \\
 \infty & \color{red}{2.0089646909885827}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You ask for an exact solution. That means solutions in [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).

Your equation is a case of the more general equations asked for in [Solving $x^{x^x}=c$ with Lambert's W function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937521/solving-xxx-c-with-lamberts-w-function/4580312#4580312).

The function $f$ with $f(x)=x^{x^x}$ doesn't have [partial inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) over non-disrete domains in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) and/or Lambert W. Therefore, your equation $x^{x^x}=17$ cannot be rearranged for $x$ by applying only Lambert W and/or elementary operations (means elementary functions) you can read from the equation.
But it is an open question if the equation has solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

Equations of your kind can be solved by generalized hyper-Lambert functions (see the references below).
$\ $

[Fantini, J.; Kloepfer, G.: Wexzal/The coupled Exponent, 1998](http://eretrandre.org/rb/files/JayFantini1998_203.pdf)

[Helms, G.: Wexzal"/"coupled exponent" , "Superroot" and a generalized Lambert-W](http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/Wexzal_Superroot.pdf)

[Galidakis, I. N.: On solving the p-th complex auxiliary equation $f^{(p)}(z)=z$. Complex Variables 50 (2005) (13) 977-997](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233129552_On_solving_the_p-th_complex_auxiliary_equation_fpzz)

[Galidakis, I. N.: On some applications of the generalized hyper-Lambert functions. Complex Variables and Elliptic Equations 52 (2007) (12) 1101-1119](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233200491_On_some_applications_of_the_generalized_hyper-Lambert_functions)

[Galidakis, I.; Weisstein, E. W.: Power Tower. Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html)