# Can we find exact value of $x$ satisfying $x^{x^x}=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function, transcendental-numbers

> Can we find exact value of $x$ satisfying $$x^{x^x}=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$$

My effort:

Let us start with the form $x=2^t$, we have
$$\Rightarrow\left(2^t\right)^{2^{t\left(2^t\right)}}=2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad 2^{t\left(2^{t\left(2^t\right)}\right)}=2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad t \times 2^{t\left(2^t\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ Now again let $t=2^m$, we get
$$2^m 2^{2^m\left(2^{2^m}\right)}=2^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \quad 2^{m+2^{m+2^m}}=2^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$
Finally we get
$$2^{m+2^m}=\frac{-1}{2}-m$$
All that i could figure out now is, by calculus, the right side straight line meets the left curve(which looks similar to $2^x$)meet at one point. By Intermediate Value Theorem, $m \in (-2,-1)$. Help needed here:

Source Image:
[image]

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that there is a solution $x$ that has a closed form expression?

Comment: If the Lambert-W function qualifies as an exact solution, there might be a chance , but it seems that the solution is not algebraic.

Comment: @BenGrossmann My question itself says "Can we find"?

Comment: @EkaveeraGouribhatla Ok, but do you have a reason to believe that there is a nice solution, or is this an equation that you invented with no prior context? This is helpful as an indication of whether it's more productive to try to find such a solution or to try to argue that no such solution exists.

Comment: There are some nice youtube videos solving this kind of equations.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I came across it in Linked In, tried hard, so posted here.Well if there is no exact form, the other person might either have posted wrong question or have a false claim of exact solution. Sorry

Comment: @EkaveeraGouribhatla So it was presented within some online post as a question that has some (presumably) clean solution. Again, that's definitely helpful context. Thanks for making the edit.

Comment: It's not clear from the image whether they mean $x^{(x^x)}$ (as you have interpreted the question) or $(x^x)^x = x^{x^2}$.

Comment: That said, the second interpretation yields the ["inelegant" expression of the solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=x%5E%28x%5E2%29%3Dsqrt%282%29%5Esqrt%282%29) $x = \exp(W(\sqrt{2}\log(2))/2)$, so that's probably not the right interpretation

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think, $x^{x^2}=a$ is trivial. Because, $(x^2)^{x^2}=a^2$, hence Lambert can solve.

Comment: @BenGrossmann i agree, the post tempted me to try hard, since it says "Only 1% people can do it" haha.

Comment: For what it's worth, [W|A gives a solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=x%5Ex*log%28x%29+%3D+log%282%29%2Fsqrt%282%29) of $x ≈ 1.37314788496323$

Comment: @EkaveeraGouribhatla If there is an answer, most likely this is an irrational algebraic number. Because, Lambert W can not solve in general.

Comment: Thank u all for your kind responses

Comment: @BenGrossmann It is a convention that exponentiation is calculated from above , if there are no parantheses.

Comment: @Peter For a lot of these online math puzzles, the punchline has to do with the puzzle-maker's intentional use of bad notation, so I wouldn't assume that the asker is following a reasonable convention

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4441297/solving-for-exact-solution-of-xxx-17/4442224#4442224

Comment: This click-bait sites don't care for quality (the "only 1% can solve" are *always* completely made up) and I suspect the question was supposed to have three $\sqrt 2$ and the answer was supposed to be $x = \sqrt 2$ (my experience is these "puzzles" *are* that stupid).  But if they made an error and it was pointed out there is no reason to fix.  If they post an unsolvalbe problem that's all the better for their concerns.

Comment: @fleablood I have a some point. For instance, can we construct an algebraic number $a$, such that $a^a=x^{x^x}$. My answer would be no. Because, there is no symmetry here.... If such $a$ exist, then the question can be meaningful. Are there such an example?... What do you think about this...

Comment: I suppose.  It's not really an area of my strength.  I was just commenting I think the creator of the puzzle probably had no answer and didn't care.  But sure, it could be an interesting question.

Comment: @fleablood I understand, we are just discussing here. I think that's good. My point would be: If there exist, at least one *another* $a$, then the question can be solvable.  But, really there is not an obvious example. I also agree that, the question is just troll. If someone's provide ,at least one example $a$, then it would be great.

Comment: @lonestudent This is probably an open question. Note that it is unknown whether $$\pi \uparrow \uparrow 4$$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

We should not expect a closed form solution in terms of elementary functions.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3314729/248217) a method for computing third super-roots ($x^{x^x}=a$) in terms of square superroots ($y^y=b$) is described. The square superroots are expressible in terms of the Lambert W function, and the iterative method appears to converge well to the third superroot given an argument greater than unity. Here, starting with $x_0=1$ gives $x_4\approx1.3731$ in four iterations, matching the computed results in the comments to the displayed digits.

Comment: Abstract -1. The exact value doesn't necessarily imply , we need Lambert  $W$. Consider, $x^x+x=6$. The exact value is $2$. But, Lambert W can not solve $x^x+x=a$, in general.

Comment: An iteration of exact values (assuming that we consider a Lambert-W expression exact) does not qualify as an EXACT solution as demanded. The Heron-method gives arbitary close rational approximations of $\sqrt{2}$ , but none of them can be exact since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. Similar situation here.