# Evaluation of $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x^{-x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Closed” form for $\sum \frac{1}{n^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/closed-form-for-sum-frac1nn)

Is it possible to evaluate this sum, and if so, how would you do it?  This question has been irritating me for a while.

$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x^{-x}$$

It clearly converges, as is proved by the comparison test:

$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x^{-x} \le \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x^{-2}=\pi^2/3!$$

An approximate value of this sum  is

$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x^{-x}\approx1.2912859970...$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any closed form solution, but we do have **Sophomore's dream**:

$$ \displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{-x} \, \text{d}x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-n}$$

The proof of this is an enjoyable exercise.