# Series as an integral (sophomore's dream)

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I need help with this exercise.

I need to prove
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{-x}\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-n}$$

I think I should use some convergence theorem, but I'm stuck.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: About the Sophomore's Dream Function : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function

Comment: This is very closely related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/closed-form-for-sum-frac1nn

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here I leave the outline. Down below you have the full solution.

$(1)$ Note that $$x^{-x}=e^{-x\log x }$$
$(2)$ $$e^u=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ u^n}{n!}$$
Use this with $u=-x\log x$

$(3)$ Since the power series converges uniformly over $[0,1]$; we may integrate termwise.
$(4)$ You'll need to evaluate $$\vartheta(n)=\int_0^1(-\log x)^n \frac{x^n}{n!}dx$$
$(5)$ Make the change of variable $-\log x\mapsto u$ and then $(n+1)u\mapsto v$

$(6)$ You should find that $$ \vartheta(n)= \frac{1}{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^{n + 1}}}}$$
You'll need the fact that $$\Gamma(n+1)=\int_0^\infty  {{v^n}{e^{ - v}}} dv=n!$$

---

Note that $$x^{-x}=e^{-x\log x }$$

Thus, you're interested in $$\int_0^1 e^{-x\log x } dx$$

Now, for every $x\in \Bbb R$, it is valid that

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ x^n}{n!}$$

Particularly

$$e^{-x \log x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ (-x\log x)^n}{n!}$$

This is
$$e^{-x \log x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-\log x)^n \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Since the power series converges uniformly over $[0,1]$; we may integrate termwise, to get

so we're interested in  $$\vartheta(n)=\int_0^1(-\log x)^n \frac{x^n}{n!}dx$$

Make a change of variable $-\log x\mapsto u$, to get

$$\vartheta(n)=\frac{1}{{n!}}\int_0^\infty  {{u^n}{e^{ - \left( {n + 1} \right)u}}} du$$

Once again, $(n+1)u\mapsto v$, so

$$\begin{align}
  \vartheta(n)&=\frac{1}{{n!}}\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{{v^n}}}{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^n}}}{e^{ - v}}} \frac{{dv}}{{n + 1}}\\ &= \frac{1}{{n!}}\frac{1}{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^{n + 1}}}}\int_0^\infty  {{v^n}{e^{ - v}}} dv ^{\color{red}{(1)}} \cr 
    \\&= \frac{1}{{n!}}\frac{1}{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^{n + 1}}}}n!  \cr 
    \\&= \frac{1}{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^{n + 1}}}} \end{align} $$

Thus, you get $$\int_0^1 {{x^{ - x}}} dx = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^{n + 1}}}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{n^n}}}} $$

as desired.

---

$\color{red}{(1)}$ This is the famous $\Gamma$ function. For natural $n$, we have $$\int_0^\infty  {{v^n}{e^{ - v}}} dv=n!$$ This can be proven by induction and integration by parts.

Comment: How can the power series converge uniformly over $[0,1]$ when it is not defined at $x = 0$?

Answer (score 9):

This is a well-known result and I remember proving it in a vector calculus course. It is hard to Google it if you do not know what it is called. This, and a similar identity are known as the **sophomore's dream** and the proof is given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SophomoresDream.html). You need to use a tricky substitution to rewrite the integral using the [gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) because
$$\Gamma(n + 1) = \int_0^\infty y^n e^{-y} dy = n!.$$

Comment: I had no idea this was so complicated.
Thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\displaystyle I(\lambda) = \int_{0}^{1}x^{\lambda}\;{dx} = \frac{1}{1+\lambda}.$ Differentiating this w.r.t. $\lambda$ we get:

$\displaystyle I^{(n)}(\lambda) = \int_{0}^{1}x^{\lambda}\ln^{n}{x}\;{dx} = \frac{(-1)^nn!}{(1+\lambda)^{n+1}}$ -- and therefore we have:

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} x^{-x} \;{dx} =  \sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \int_{0}^{1}x^n\ln^n{x}\;{dx} = \sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{1}{(1+n)^{n+1}}$

and $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} x^{x} \;{dx} =  \sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{1}{n!} \int_{0}^{1}x^n\ln^n{x}\;{dx} = \sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(1+n)^{n+1}}$.