# Determine value the following: $L=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Determine value the following: $$L=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^k}$$

My try:

Put $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^k}\to a_{n}-a_{n-1}=\frac{1}{n^n}>0$$

$\to \left\{a_n\right\}$ sequence increasing.

And
$$a_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^k}=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k^k}<1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}<1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{(k-1)k}=2-\frac{1}{n}<2$$

$\to \left\{a_n\right\}$ sequence converge.

But come here, I don't know how to determine value

Therefore, please help me, I need a solution.

Comment: there is no explicit value

Comment: See [Sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream)

Comment: See  http://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function

Comment: This has been answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237513/series-as-an-integral-sophomores-dream)

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^k}=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{x^x}dx$$
([Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream#Historical_proof) has a proof.)

Comment: Why is that true?

Comment: True, not true: whatever. **What's** the proof ?!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: why download it?....