# Infinite series $\sum\frac{1}{n^n}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm just wondering is there a proof for the sum of the series of general term $\frac{1}{n^n}$. I can't seem to find one online. I know it converges pretty fast but I can't think how you could begin to solve it.

Comment: You mean an explicit formula for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}$?

Comment: IF you want a proof of convergences why not use the root test?

Comment: Do you want the value of the sum, or just a proof the series converges? If the later, noting that $\frac{1}{n^n} = o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ immediately gives it.

Comment: I know how to prove convergence but not its sum

Comment: I just thought that it would be something elegant like the sum of 1/n^2    because its such a simple series

Comment: possible duplicate of [Series as an integral (sophomore's dream)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237513/series-as-an-integral-sophomores-dream)

Comment: "Proof for the sum" does not mean anything. What precisely are you asking?

Answer (score 4):

There is an amazing result that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^x}\ .$$
This gives you some kind of sum though of course it's not a simple evaluation.

I haven't been able to locate a reference for this result, maybe someone else can help.

Comment: that is kinda cool, do you have a proof of the statement I'd love to see it. Haven't a clue how you'd start to evaluate the integral though

Comment: Thanks @qwr for providing the name "Sophomore's Dream", looking it up will locate a proof [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237513).

Answer (score 1):

It's called Sophomore's Dream, and is equal to

$$ \int_0^1 x^{-x}\ dx $$ around 1.291285997.

Comment: That is class, thanks, just googled it, couldn't find it without the name.