# Prove serial representation of the integral $\int_0^1 x^x \,{\rm d}x$

Tags: calculus

I have to prove the serial representation of:
\begin{equation*}
\int^1_0 x^x\,{\rm d}x=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^n}.
\end{equation*}

It obtains:
\begin{equation*}
x^x=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(f(x))^n}{n!}.
\end{equation*}

The function $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237513/series-as-an-integral-sophomores-dream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever heard of the [Sophomore's Dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)? In this wiki article there is a proof of the first identity. I believe this solves your problem.