# Prove that $\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^x}\, dx<2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation, special-functions

> Prove that $$\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^x}\, dx<2.$$
>
> <sub>Note: This inequality is rather tight. The integral approximates to $1.9955$.</sub>

Integration by parts is out of the question. If we let $f(x)=\dfrac1{x^x}$ and $g'(x)=1$ then $f'(x)=-x^{-x}(\ln x + 1)$ by implicit differentiation and $g(x)=x$. The integral $\int f'(x)g(x)\, dx$ looks even harder to evaluate.

Expressing the left-hand side as a Frullani integral $$\int_0^\infty\frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}x\, dx=(f(0)-f(\infty))\ln\frac ba$$ means that $f(ax)-f(bx)=x^{1-x}$. However, I can't seem to find a continuous function $f$ that satisfies the functional equation. Is there such a function?

<sub>(For context, user371838's post below proves sophomore's dream which I also asked about originally.)</sub>

Comment: just an idea (I dont know if this can work): try to compare your integral with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}<2$

Comment: Interesting - Via a substitution $x^x=e^u$ the integral should be transformable to 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^u}\left(\frac{1}{W(u)}-\frac{1}{W(u)(1+W(u))}\right)\mathrm{d}u$$
But Mathematica gives me the numerical result $0.70417$ - I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: Maybe equation 6.3.7 in https://www.scribd.com/document/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function can help.

Comment: Univesal approach presented [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607028/show-that-int-0-inftyx-xdx-pi-ln-pi/4634329#4634329).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Remarks*: Here is an alternative proof.
I used the same bounds for this question
[Improper integral inequality including the golden ratio and the Sophomore's dream](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190937/improper-integral-inequality-including-the-golden-ratio-and-the-sophomores-drea)

---

We will use the following auxiliary results (Facts 1-2).

**Fact 1**: $x^{-x} \le \frac{3 - x}{x^2 - x + 2}$ for all $x \in [1, 2]$.
(RHS is the Pade $(1, 2)$ approximation of $x^{-x}$ at $x = 1$.)

**Fact 2**: $x^{-x} \le a^{-x} \mathrm{e}^{-x + a}$ for all $x, a > 0$.
(*Proof*: Taking logarithm on both sides, letting $u = \frac{a}{x} > 0$,
it is equivalent to $\ln u \le u - 1$ which is true (easy).)

---

We have (Sophomore's dream)
$$I_1 := \int_0^1 x^{-x} \mathrm{d} x
= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n + 1)^{n + 1}}
\le 1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{n + 1}} = \frac{2233}{1728}.$$

Using Fact 1, we have
$$I_2 := \int_1^2 x^{-x}\mathrm{d} x
\le \int_1^2 \frac{3 - x}{x^2 - x + 2}\mathrm{d} x = \frac{5}{\sqrt 7}\arctan \frac{\sqrt 7}{5} - \frac12\ln 2.$$

Using Fact 2, we have
$$I_3 := \int_2^{5/2} x^{-x}\,\mathrm{d} x
\le \int_2^{5/2} 2^{-x}\mathrm{e}^{-x + 2}\,\mathrm{d} x = \frac{2 - \sqrt{2\mathrm{e}^{-1}}}{8 + 8\ln 2},$$
and
$$I_4 :=
 \int_{5/2}^3 x^{-x}\,\mathrm{d} x
\le \int_{5/2}^3 (5/2)^{-x}\mathrm{e}^{-x + 5/2}\,\mathrm{d} x = \frac{4\sqrt{10} - 8\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{-1}}}{125\ln \frac{5}{2} + 125}, $$
and
$$I_5 := 
\int_3^\infty x^{-x}\, \mathrm{d} x
\le \int_3^\infty 3^{-x} \mathrm{e}^{-x + 3}\, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{27\ln 3 + 27}.$$

Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\int_0^\infty x^{-x} \mathrm{d} x\\
 =\, & I_1 + I_2 + I_3 + I_4 + I_5\\
 \le\,& \frac{2233}{1728} 
 + \frac{5}{\sqrt 7}\arctan \frac{\sqrt 7}{5} - \frac12\ln 2
 + \frac{2 - \sqrt{2\mathrm{e}^{-1}}}{8 + 8\ln 2} + \frac{4\sqrt{10} - 8\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{-1}}}{125\ln \frac{5}{2} + 125}
 + \frac{1}{27\ln 3 + 27}\\
 <\,& 2.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: Would you know of any tight lower bounds for $x^{-x}$ for $1<x<5$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Can we construct some lower bounds using Erik Satie's idea for upper bound: $ex^{\frac{12}{1000}+\frac{2}{5}}e^{-x^{\frac{12}{1000}+1+\frac{2}{5}}}\geq x^{-x}$?

Comment: Actually, I think I need lower bounds for $\left(\frac{\ln x}x\right)^x$ over $1<x<e$ instead. Please see [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417026/is-int-0-inftydx-over-xxxx-int-0-inftydx-over-xxxxxx#comment1130814_438432), I'm trying to get an analytical bound that is sharper than $2$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire You want to estimate $\int_1^e\left(\frac{\log u}u\right)^{eu/(e-1)}\,du$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire We may use lower bound of $\ln u$ or $\frac{\ln u}{u}$ first.

Answer (score 12):

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x\log x}\,dx = \underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x\log x}\,dx}_{I_1}+\underbrace{\int_{1}^{+\infty}e^{-x\log x}\,dx}_{I_2} $$

$$ I_1=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}x^n\left(\log x\right)^n\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^n}\tag{A}$$

$$ I_2 = \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(x+1)\log(x+1)}\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{W(x)+1}\,dx\tag{B} $$
where $(A)$ gives $I_1\leq 1.292$ and high-order Padé approximants give  $I_2\leq 0.705$.
It is a very tight inequality: I wonder if it can be proved in a more elementary way, maybe by writing the whole integral as $\int_{1}^{+\infty}e^{-x}g(W(x))\,dx$.

Answer (score 12):

This approach is based on the intermediate inequalities, which follow from the series representations.

Using  [inequality](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7Bx%5E-x%2C1%2Bx%20e%20%28e%5Ee%5E-1%20-1%29%282-ex%29%2B%20sqrt%20%28e%20x%29%20%28ex-1%29%5E2%28116%20-ex%29%2F635%20%7D.%7B%7B1%2C0%2C-100%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C100%7D%7D%2C%7Bx%2C0.0%2C%201.%7D)
$$x^{-x}\le1+(\sqrt[e]e -1)ex(2-ex)+ \frac{116-ex}{635} \sqrt{e x} (ex-1)^2,\quad\text{if}\quad x\in[0,1],\tag1$$
[image: Approximation 1]

one can get
$$I_1 \le \dfrac1e\int\limits_0^e (1 + (\sqrt[e]e - 1) (2 y - y^2) + \dfrac{116-y}{635} \sqrt y\, (y - 1)^2)\,\text dy,$$
$${\small I_1 \le 1 - e + \dfrac{e^2}3 + \sqrt e\left(\dfrac{232}{1905} - \dfrac{466 e}{3175} + \dfrac{236 e^2}{4445} - \dfrac{2 e^3}{5715}\right) + \dfrac{\sqrt[e]e (3e-e^2)}3 < 1.291733}\tag2$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha integration](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20%7B%281%2B%28e%5Ee%5E-1%20-1%29%282y-y%5E2%29%2B%20sqrt%20y%20%20%28y-1%29%5E2%28116%20-y%29%2F635%29%2Fe%20%7D%2C%7By%2C0.0%2C%20e%7D)).

If $\;x\in[1,3],\;$ [then](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7Bx%5E-x%2C%20%28%282-x%29%281%2B%28x-1%29%5E6%2F120%29%20%2B%20%28x%20-%201%29%5E3%20%28x%5E2-6x%2B11%29%20%2F12%29%20%2B%20%28x-1%29%5E8%20%2F602910%20*%28470%20%2B381%28x-e%29%20-270%20%28x-e%29%5E2%20%2B115%28x-e%29%5E3%29%7D.%7B%7B1%2C0%2C-5000%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C5000%7D%7D%2C%7B%20x%2C%201.%2C%203%7D)
$$\begin{align}
&(2-x)\left(1+\dfrac1{120}(x-1)^6\right) + \dfrac1{12}(x-1)^3 (x^2-6x+11)\\[4pt]
&+ \dfrac1{602910}(x-1)^8(470 +381(x-e) -270 (x-e)^2 +115(x-e)^3) -x^{-x} \le 0,
\end{align}\tag3$$
[image: Approximation 2]
$$\begin{align}
&I_2 = \int\limits_1^3 x^{-x}\,\text dx \le \int\limits_0^2\bigg(1-y)\left(1+\dfrac1{120}y^6\right) + \dfrac1{12}y^3 (y^2-4y+6) + \dfrac1{602910}y^8\\[4pt]
&\times\bigg(470 +381(y+1-e) -270 (y+1-e)^2 +115(y+1-e)^3\bigg)\bigg)\,\text dy = \bigg(\dfrac{y^9}{5426190}\\[4pt]
&\times\left(\dfrac{345}4 y^3 - \dfrac{135(23e - 5)}{11} y^2 + \dfrac{27(62 - 50 e + 115 e^2)}{10} y + 696 - 186 e + 75 e^2 - 115 e^3\right) \\[4pt]
& - y^8/960 + y^7/840 + y^6/72 - y^5/15 + y^4/8 - y^2/2 + y\bigg)\bigg|_0^2,
\end{align}$$
$$I_2 \le \dfrac{2 (61687647 - 11159040 e + 4899840 e^2 - 809600 e^3)}{149220225} 
< 0.687550.\tag4$$

At last,
$$I_3 = \int\limits_3^\infty x^{-x}\,\text dx = 3\int\limits_0^\infty (3+3y)^{-3-3y}\,\text dy = 3\int\limits_0^\infty3^{-3-3y}(1+y)^{-3-3y}\,\text dy$$
$$I_3 \le \dfrac19\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{27^{-y}}{(1+y)^3}\,\text dy 
= \dfrac{1-3\ln3\,(1 + 81\ln3\, \text{Ei}(-3\ln3))}{18} < 0.018865\tag5$$
(see also [WA integration](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Einfty%2027%5E-y%2F%20%281%2By%29%5E3%20dy))

From $(2),(4),(5)$ should
$$I=I_1+I_2+I_3 < 1.9982 <2.$$

On the other hand,
$$I_1=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac1{n^n}\le 1+\dfrac14+\dfrac1{27} +\dfrac1{256} + \dfrac1{3125}+\sum\limits_{n=6}^\infty\dfrac1{n^6},$$
$$I_1 \le 1+\dfrac14+\dfrac1{27} +\dfrac1{256} + \dfrac1{3125}+\dfrac{\pi^6}{945} < 1.291302,$$

$$\color{brown}{\mathbf{I< 1.291302 + 0.687550 + 0.018865 < 1.99772}}.$$

Comment: I did not know 25 bounty was possible.

Comment: @TymaGaidash The half-award is the often realized situation.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Also, the lowest bounty I could do was 50 and the highest I saw, not do, was 1000 for a goodbye post.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I never asked questions and never started bounties in MSE. At the same time, often I've got only half part of the announced bounty award.

Comment: Beat answer by far.

Comment: @K.defaoite [This my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx/4041295#4041295) looks as the best my work in MSE.

Answer (score 5):

> This is a well-known result but it is hard to Google it if you do not know what it is called. This, and a similar identity are known as the **sophomore's dream** and the proof is given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SophomoresDream.html).

---

**Important Note:** This Proof is also present in Nahin’s *Inside Interesting Integrals*. However, this is how we learnt it in class as well.

---

We start with the identity $$x^{cx^a} = e^{cx^a\ln x} \tag 1$$ where $a$ and $c$ are constants. Using the power series expansion of the exponential $$e^y =  1 + y + \frac{y^2}{2!} + … $$ with $y = cx^a \ln x$ gives us: $$x^{cx^a} = 1+ cx^a\ln x + \frac{1}{2!}c^2x^{2a}\ln^2 x + \ldots $$ and so: $$\int_{0}^{1} x^{cx^a} \, dx = \int_{0}^{1}\, dx + c\int_{0}^1{} x^a \ln x\, dx + \frac{c^2}{2!} \int_{0}^{1} x^{2a}\ln^2 x\, dx + \ldots \tag 2$$

Now, to solve integrals of the form: $$I(m,n) = \int_{0}^{1} x^m\ln^n x \, dx $$ we simply make the substitution $u=-\ln x$, followed by another substitution $\chi = (m+1)u$ giving us: $$I(m,n) = \frac{(-1)^nn!}{(m+1)^{n+1}}$$

Hence, $(2)$ becomes $$\int_{0}^{1} x^{cx^a}\, dx = 1- \frac{c}{(a+1)^2} + \frac{c^2}{(2a+1)^3} - \frac{c}{(3a+1)^4}+\ldots$$

Now, if $c=-1$ and if $a=1$, it gives us: $$\int_{0}^{1} x^{-x}\, dx = 1 + \frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\ldots$$

---

See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237513/series-as-an-integral-sophomores-dream).

Comment: but the integral is from zero to infinity

Answer (score 4):

This comment is not the proof, just wanted to share a quick idea. Lots of assumptions, because no proofs are provided.

Assume we know that $a(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^x}\, dx = a< \infty$. Then $a(x)/a$ is the valid probability density of some random variable, say $B$. Due to the Markov inequality we have
$$
P(B>1)={1 \over a} \int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^x}dx < {1 \over a} \int_0^\infty\frac{x}{x^x}dx,
$$
wherefrom we get
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^x}dx < \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^{x-1}}dx.
$$

Assume the integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^{x-1}}dx=
\int_0^\infty a_1(x) dx=a_1<\infty$. Then $a_1(x)/a_1$
is the valid probability density of some random variable, say $B_1$. Again due to the Markov inequality we have
$$
P(B_1>1)={1 \over a_1} \int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^{x-1}}dx < {1 \over a_1} \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^{x-2}}dx.
$$
Proceeding in the same way we get
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^x}dx <  \int_0^1\frac{1}{x^{x}}dx +  \int_0^1\frac{1}{x^{x-1}}dx
+
\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^{x-2}}dx
+ \int_0^1\frac{1}{x^{x-3}}dx
+\dots
=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\int_0^1 {x^{n-x}}dx
$$

Since Markov bound is very crude, not sure if this converges.

Comment: Although this is interesting, switching the integral and summation will yield
$$\int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n-x} \mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{-x}}{1-x}\mathrm{d}x$$
Which does not converge.

Comment: It seems like we are not allowed to switch integration and summation here since the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n-x}$ is not uniformly convergent. If we denote the remainder $r_n(x)={x^{-x} \over 1- x} - \sum_{k=0}^n x^{k-x}$, then there does not exist $n_0$ such that for $n>n_0$, $|r_n(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$. For example, $r_n(1)=\infty$.

Comment: I decided to look deeper into the issue. Denote by $F(x)$ the cumulative distribution function of the Uniform random variable on [0,1]. Then $F(x)=(x-0)/(1-0)=x$, $x \in [0,1]$. Then the integral $\int_0^1 {x^{n-x}}dx$
is, in fact, Stieltjes integral $\int_0^1 {x^{n-x}}dF(x)$. Using the property of Stieltjes integral we can exclude $x=1$ from integration. Let $(1-0)$ mean that point 1 is excluded. Then  we get $\int_0^{1-0} {x^{n-x}}dF(x)+[F(1)-F(1-0)]1^{n-1}=\int_0^{1-0} {x^{n-x}}dF(x)$. Seems like now we can switch the integration and summation. But does it help?

Answer (score 1):

Big hint for the new year .

I simplify the answer of RiverLi we have for $x\in[1,3]$:

$$2^{1.449}x^{\frac{42}{100}}e^{-x^{1+\frac{42}{100}}}>x^{-x}$$

And using the Sophomore dream as RiverLi we have :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-x}dx<\int_{1}^{3}2^{1.449}x^{\frac{42}{100}}e^{-x^{1+\frac{42}{100}}}dx+\int_{0}^{1}x^{-x}dx+\int_{3}^{\infty}3^{-x}e^{\left(-x+3\right)}dx<2$$

All the integral are easy and we are done !

---

---

---

Edit we have better in fact :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-x}dx<\int_{1}^{5}ex^{\frac{12}{1000}+\frac{2}{5}}e^{-x^{\frac{12}{1000}+1+\frac{2}{5}}}dx+\int_{0}^{1}x^{-x}dx+\int_{5}^{\infty}x^{-x}dx$$

Or :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-x}dx<\int_{1}^{5}ex^{\frac{12}{1000}+\frac{2}{5}}e^{-x^{\frac{12}{1000}+1+\frac{2}{5}}}dx+\int_{0}^{1}x^{-x}dx+\int_{5}^{\infty}5^{-x}dx$$

Where we have the inequality for $x\in[1,5]$ :

$$ex^{\frac{12}{1000}+\frac{2}{5}}e^{-x^{\frac{12}{1000}+1+\frac{2}{5}}}\geq x^{-x}\tag{I}$$

This inequality can be hadle with logarithm and derivative .

It leads us to using the Sophomore dream as RiverLi :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-x}dx<e\cdot\frac{250}{353}\left(\frac{1}{e}-e^{-5^{1+\frac{103}{250}}}\right)+\frac{1}{3125\ln5}+\frac{27891287}{21600000}+\frac{1}{38800}<2$$

Or :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-x}dx<\frac{250}{353}+\frac{1}{3125\ln5}+\frac{27891287}{21600000}+\frac{1}{38800}<2$$

I don't know if it could be shown by hand .

Some details :

$(I)$ proof :

We introduce the function :

$$f(x)=\ln\left(ex^{\frac{12}{1000}+\frac{2}{5}}e^{-x^{\frac{12}{1000}+1+\frac{2}{5}}}\right)-\ln\left(x^{-x}\right)$$

We have :

$$f'(x)=-\frac{353}{250}x^{\frac{103}{250}}+\frac{103}{250x}+1+\ln x$$

And :

$$f''(x)=\frac{-\left(36359x^{\frac{353}{250}}-62500x+25750\right)}{62500x^{2}}$$

The interesting part of the second dervative is :

$$g(x)=-\left(36359x^{\frac{353}{250}}-62500x+25750\right)$$

We have :

$$g'\left(\frac{61035156250000000\cdot2^{\frac{29}{103}}\cdot5^{\frac{87}{103}}}{164730217164529\cdot103^{\frac{44}{103}}\cdot353^{\frac{88}{103}}}\right)=0$$

Wich says for this value the function $g(x)$ have a maxima and :

$g(2.134...)=0$

Call $U=2.134...$

Now for $f'(x)$ we have $f(1)=0$ and $f'(x)$ is increasing before $x\in[1,U]$ and decreasing for $[U,5]$ with a zero at $V=3.66...$

Recalling that $f(1)=0,f(5)>0$ it shows the inequality $(I)$

For the integral :

$$\int_{1}^{5}ex^{\frac{12}{1000}+\frac{2}{5}}e^{-x^{\frac{12}{1000}+1+\frac{2}{5}}}dx$$

have the form $p'(x)r'(p(x))$ which is straightforward to integrating .

For the Sophomore Dream see RiverLi's answer .

Comment: Nota Bene : $2^{1.449}\simeq \frac{3}{\ln3}$

Comment: @RiverLi What do you think about ? Happy New Year !

Comment: Happy New year! Would you please give a complete detailed proof without 'hint', 'edit', 'all the integrals are easy' etc.

Comment: Also, first, you need to give a proof of $2^{1.449}x^{\frac{42}{100}}e^{-x^{1+\frac{42}{100}}}>x^{-x}$ for $x\in [1, 3]$.

Comment: @RiverLi See the second part I add some materials .

Comment: @RiverLi I stop to do maths and leave this community have fun for 2023!Goodbye.

Comment: The form of $ex^{\frac{12}{1000}+\frac{2}{5}}e^{-x^{\frac{12}{1000}+1+\frac{2}{5}}}\geq x^{-x}$ is nice. But the proof for it is not addressed well. Anyway, it is nice. (+1)

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks you ! If you want you can post a question on it and if you want to see me I'm on music and theory .

Comment: Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but somehow interesting observation:
$$\int_0^\infty x^{-x}dx=\int_0^1 x^{-x}dx+\int_1^2 x^{-x}dx+\int_2^3 x^{-x}dx+\dots=$$
$$\int_0^1 x^{-x}dx+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1(x+n)^{-(x+n)}dx.$$
The second term $\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty(x+n)^{-(x+n)}dx$ looks like "double sophomore dream"; in $n$ as summation ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}$) and in $x$ as integral ($\int_0^1 x^{-x}dx$). But I don't know what to do with this next.

It would be nice to be able to find a tight bound, e.g., in terms of "sophomore dream" value. Note that $\left(\int_0^1x^{-x}dx\right)^{\int_0^1x^{-x}dx}=1.29128599^{-1.29128599}\approx 0.71885$.

Answer (score 0):

Some toughts :

See https://www.isr-publications.com/jnsa/articles-1563-proofs-of-three-open-inequalities-with-power-exponential-functions

Using Vasc's lemma 7.1 we have :

$$a\left(\left((1-c)^{2}+ac(2-c)-ac(1-c)\ln a\right)\right)\geq x^{-x}$$

For $x\in[1,2]$ where $a=\frac{1}{x}$ and $c=x-1$

---

---

We have also :

$$\left(\frac{\left((1-c)^{2}+ac(2-c)-ac(1-c)\ln a\right)}{a^{b}}\right)^{\frac{1}{b}}\geq x^{-x}$$

For $x\in [0.5,1]$ and $c=2\left(1-x\right)$ , $b=2$ , $a=x$

---

---

And again :

$$a^{2}\left(\left((1-c)^{2}+ac(2-c)-ac(1-c)\ln a\right)\right)\geq x^{-x}$$

For $x\in[2,3]$ and $a=\frac{1}{x}$ and $c=x-2$

---

---

For other value we can be inspired by strong convexity/concavity of :

$$f\left(x\right)=x^{ax}$$

We have on $x\in(0,0.25]$  and $a=-3$:

$$\left(\frac{1}{f'\left(0.25\right)\left(x-0.25\right)+f\left(0.25\right)+\frac{\left(x-0.25\right)^{2}f''\left(0.25\right)}{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{a}}\geq x^{-x}$$

Hope it helps .

Edit 22/04/2022 :

There is simpler we have on $(0.5,2)$ :

$$f\left(x\right)=\left(1+\frac{\left(x^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{1-\left(x^{\frac{1}{2}}-1\right)^{2}}\right)-1\right)x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2}\right)^{\left(-2\right)}-x^{-x}\ge0$$

So see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+%5Cleft%281%2B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%28x%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%7D%7D%7B1-%5Cleft%28x%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%7D-1%5Cright%29%5E%7B2%7D%7D%5Cright%29-1%5Cright%29x%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%7D%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright%29%5E%7B%5Cleft%28-2%5Cright%29%7D+at+0.5+to+2&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Integral%22%2C+%22rangestart%22%7D+-%3E%220.5%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22integral%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Integral%22%2C+%22integrand%22%7D+-%3E%22%281%2B%28%28%28x%5E%28%28%281%29%2F%282%29%29%29%28%28%28x%5E%28%28%281%29%2F%282%29%29%29%29%2F%281-%28x%5E%28%28%281%29%2F%282%29%29%29-1%29%5E%282%29%29%29%29-1%29x%5E%28%28%281%29%2F%282%29%29%29%29%2F%282%29%29%29%5E%28%28-2%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Integral%22%2C+%22rangeend%22%7D+-%3E%222%22

Edit 26/07/2022 :

We have the inequality for $0<x\leq 1$ :

$$\frac{\left(4-\frac{292}{100}x^{\frac{7}{10}}\left(x^{\frac{7}{10}}-1\right)\right)}{4+\frac{292}{100}x^{\frac{7}{10}}\left(x^{\frac{7}{10}}-1\right)}\geq x^{-x}$$