# Area under $\frac{1}{x^x}$ curve

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum, tetration, power-towers

How can I calculate area under $\frac{1}{x^x}$ on any interval, I tried the Archimedes  method, but I get

$$\frac1n\sum \frac 1{X_n^{X_n} }$$

and that's very complex to calculate because of the roots, is there an easier method to calculate this?

Comment: $1/x^x$ does not have an antiderivative that can be expressed in elementary terms.  Also, you should probably restrict to $x > 0$ to avoid complex numbers and to ensure that your function is defined.

Comment: I don’t think there is a closed form for the area under this curve over an arbitrary interval. I am not sure a closed form exists for any interval (though $(0,\infty)$ may be an exception).

Comment: I doubt you will do better than approximations.  For example $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{1}{x^x} \, dx \approx 1.291286$ and $\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^x} \, dx \approx 1.995456$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585634/prove-that-int-0-infty-frac1xx-dx2

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the short answer, but here is the link with my work. It needs a better form though. You can also use the definition of the Riemann Sum to find another value.

> ([My Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4135449/area-under-the-graph-of-a-number-multiplied-by-itself-a-negative-amount-of-times))

Using the definition of the Riemann Sum, we can rewrite this as:

$$\mathrm{\int_{\Bbb R^+}x^{-x}dx=\lim_{b,n\to \infty}\frac bn \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{bk}{n}\right)^{-\left(\frac{bk}{n}\right)},n\gg b}$$

Here is proof of this result: [Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ictlmmzqwy)

Comment: Thank you all so much

Comment: Yes, I know and I'm very thankful for your answer. . But sorry for late response, I opened this today.

Comment: @michalMravec Sure and what do you mean by “open”?