# Area under $x^{-x}$ over its real domain. What is another non-integral form of $\int_{\Bbb R^+}x^{-x}dx$?

Tags: area, alternative-proof, constants, tetration, power-towers

A few years ago, I got interested in an apparently hard integration problem which had me fascinated. This was the integral of a Sophomore Dream like integral except with the bounds over the real positive numbers denoted by $\Bbb R^+$ and not from 0 to 1 over the unit square, or unit line in this case? Nevertheless, this quirky problem caught my attention for having its area be almost 2 with this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xuntecgloz). Here is my solution, although there are a couple of calculations that I could have done differently:
[image]
$$ A\mathit =\mathrm{\int_{\Bbb R^+}x^{-x}dx=\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^n ln^n(x)}{n!}dx}$$

I naively used Wolfram Alpha to integrate, but this can easily be still done with the substitution of $x=e^{-y}$ which is similar to the other [Sophomore Dream integrals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream), so it will be ignored here for conciseness and should be able to use an interchanging theorem. Here I chose not to do the substitution as the same result appears anyways and this is simpler:

$$\mathrm{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^{\infty}x^n ln^n(x)dx= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}(-x^{-n}x^nln^n(x)ln(x)ln^{-(n+1)}(x)(-1)^{-(n+1)}(n+1)^{-(n+1)}Γ\big(n+1,-(n+1)ln(x)\big)\big|_0^{\infty}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{Γ\big(n+1,-(n+1)ln(\infty)\big)}{Γ(n+1)(n+1)^{n+1}}}$$

This  -$\infty$ in the gamma function argument does not seem to exist, but taking a limit helps as well as some other forms with the [Regularized Incomplete Gamma Function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/GammaRegularized/):
$$A=\mathrm{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-n}\frac{Γ(n,-\infty n)}{Γ(n)}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{Q(n,-nx)}{n^n}=1.99545595…}$$

As seen from the link, the index n has to be a natural number which is true here. Also, there are other forms with the exponential sum function, and other series representations if non-elementary functions are not allowed. Here is [proof](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+Q%28x%2C-3x%29%2Fx%5Ex+from+1+to+1000) of this answer from Wolfram Alpha.

Please do not give me any integral expressions of this constant, but rather special functions or other representations are encouraged. I will “check” the best answer. I just need a “nice” non-integral expression of the constant. Please give me feedback and correct me!

An alternate form solution is very needed for this problem also concerning power tower, so please check it out. I have left my context, attempts, and questions, therefore any help with alternate forms for either of these would be appreciated.

Using the definition of the Riemann Sum, we can rewrite this as:

$$\mathrm{\int_{\Bbb R^+}x^{-x}dx=\lim_{b,n\to \infty}\frac bn \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{bk}{n}\right)^{-\left(\frac{bk}{n}\right)},n\gg b}$$

Here is proof of this result: [Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ictlmmzqwy)

Here are some unlikely [closed forms.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.99545595750013800041872469845272435208621663696797887278830006098303161714656636306695492778946387705816763770)

There is also a form of the constant using a summation expansion. Here is proof of a third form of this constant [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uyvdvtjpdq): $$\mathrm{A= \lim_{x\to \infty}\sum_{n\ge 1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k e^{nx} n^{k-n}x^k}{k!}}$$

Here is another sum and double sum answer [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tq5qjafgyg). This has a sophomore dream in the solution plus the same integrand from 1 to $\infty$:
$$\mathrm{A=\sum_{n\ge 1}n^{-n}-\lim_{x\to \infty}\sum_{n\ge1}\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{(-x)^n(nx)^k}{(k+n)k!n!}}$$

Let $\bar F$ represent a Regularized Hypergeometric function then, as $\mathrm{Q(n,-nx)= 1-(-nx)^n\ _1\bar F_1(n,n+1,nx)}$, the following can be proven with the [Kummer Confluent Hypergeometric Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html): $$\mathrm{\sum_{n\ge1}n^{-n}-\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n\ge1}(-x)^n\  _1\bar F_1(n,n+1,nx)}$$

Also, feel free to use [these](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/06/01/04/01/02/) identities to find an alternate form. I could go on, but I have found no form that does not need a limit in the answer.

Comment: It's not a competition to see who can use the most fonts in one post.

Comment: There is a funny-looking A. There is a display that's about ten feet high. There is boldface. There is Fraktur in blue. It's too busy (for my taste).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Do you have any alternate forms for this constant? You seem very talented and I would love to see some possible closed forms of this constant, although a closed form is optional as this does not seem to have one. You can also click the fraktur link, that is the default link color. Please no integral defined forms as we are trying to evaluate this integral, and find the area more importantly!

Comment: It's tabulated to over 100 digits at https://oeis.org/A229191 where there is also a reference to Finch's book and links to some related constants. I doubt there's a closed form.

Comment: @GerryMyerson   Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124507/discussion-between-tyma-gaidash-and-gerry-myerson)!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything more than what's at the oeis. I encourage you to follow the links there.

Comment: Just as a joke $$\frac{2+6 \sqrt{2}-6 \sqrt{3}-2 e+3 \pi +4 \pi ^2+8 \log (2)+2 \log (3)}{2+3   \sqrt{2}-6 \sqrt{3}+5 e+4 \pi -\log (2)+4 \log (3)}$$ gives 18 exact decimals.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I found 12 other jokes [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.99545595750013800041872469845272435208621663696797887278830006098303161714656636306695492778946387705816763770225900794060621249107688533388679744) with possible closed forms. However, a non-closed form would also work. Any ideas?

Comment: I know a form: $$A\bar =\int_{\Bbb R^+} x^{-x} dx=\int_0^{1/e} x^{-x} dx+\int_0^\sqrt[e]e-\frac{ln(x)}{W(-ln(x)}dx -e^{\frac 1e-1}≈.48-.53+2.04=A$$. I already figured out the $x^{-x}$ integral and can use something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168572/integral-over-domain-of-infinite-tetration-of-x-over-its-real-domain-from-0-to) to solve for the productlog/w-lambert integral…

Comment: So far I have to use a single series for this middle integral. To integrate, I used a theorem about the integral of an inverse function, but this diverges. I must use an inversion theorem  to find a double sum solution. The goal is to get rid of the limit at the beginning and find a more elementary solution. The first integral is $$ .48≈\sum_{n\ge1}\frac {Q(n,n)}{n^n}=\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{E_{-n}(n+1)}{n!}$$ with the generalized  exponential integral function.

Comment: Yay 1000 reputation!!…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a note**. I will try to find more in the near future.
$$
I=\int^{\infty}_{0}x^{-x}dx=\int^{\infty}_{1}e^{-x\log x}dx+\int^{1}_{0}x^{-x}dx.
$$
Using $\sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-n}=\int^{1}_{0}x^{-x}dx$ and making the change of variable $x\rightarrow e^{W(x)}$ where $W(x)$ is the well known Lambert function, we get
$$
I=\sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-n}+\int^{\infty}_{0}\exp\left(-e^{W(x)}W(x)\right)e^{W(x)}W'(x)dx=
$$
$$
=\sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-n}+\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-x}e^{W(x)}W'(x)dx=\sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-n}+\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-x}d\left(e^{W(x)}\right)=
$$
$$
\textrm{ integration by parts }
$$
$$
=\sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-n}-1+\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-x}e^{W(x)}dx=\sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-n}-1+\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-x}\frac{x}{W(x)}dx
$$
If we make the change of variable $x\rightarrow -\log t$ we arrive easily to
$$
I=\sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-n}-1+\int^{1}_{0}t\frac{-\log t}{W(-\log t)}\frac{-dt}{t}=\sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-n}-1+\int^{1}_{0}\frac{-\log t}{W(-\log t)}dt.
$$
But the function $h(z)=\frac{W(-\log z)}{-\log z}$, is the analytic continuation of the Euler's iterated exponential function $z^{z^{z^{\ldots}}}$. Hence finaly we can write
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{1}{x^x}dx=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^n}-1+\int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{t^{t^{t^{ \ldots}}}}dt.
$$
In the sense $z^{z^{z^{\ldots}}}=h(z)$.

**REVISED.**

Assume that $W(t)$ is the well known Lambert function. Then for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$, we have
$$
\int^{M}_{0}\frac{t^k}{1+W(t)}dt=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}k!}{(k+1)^{k+1}}+
$$
$$
+\frac{M^{k+1} k!}{W(M)^{k+1}(k+1)^{k+1}}\sum_{0\leq j\leq k}(-1)^{j+k}\frac{(k+1)^jW(M)^j}{j!}.
$$
Hence
$$
\int^{M}_{0}\frac{e^{-t}}{1+W(t)}dt=-\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{1}{(k+1)^{k+1}}+
$$
$$
+\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{e^{-(k+1)W(M)} M^{k+1}W(M)^{-k-1}\Gamma(k+1,-(k+1)W(M))}{(k+1)^{k}(k+1)!}=
$$
$$
=-\sum_{k\geq 1}k^{-k}+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\Gamma(k,-kW(M))}{k^{k-1}k!},\tag 1
$$
where
$$
\Gamma(a,z)=\int^{\infty}_{z}e^{-t}t^{a-1}dt
$$
is the incomplete Gamma function. But one can see with the help of (1) easily that
$$
\int^{M}_{1}x^{-x}dx=\int^{M\log M}_{0}\frac{e^{-t}}{1+W(t)}dt=-\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}k^{-k}+\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{\Gamma(k,-kW(M\log M))}{(k!) k^{k-1}}.
$$
Hence using $\int^{1}_{0}x^{-x}dx=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}k^{-k}$, we get
$$
\int^{M}_{0}x^{-x}dx=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{\Gamma(k,-k\log M)}{(k!) k^{k-1}}\textrm{, }\forall M>0.\tag 2
$$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Identities at the end of the section and deffinition of the W-Lambert function.

Comment: The function $h(x)=x^{x^{x^{\ldots}}}$ converges in $\textbf{R}$ only for $e^{-e}\leq x\leq e^{1/e}$. That is why I use analytic continuation. Actualy $g(x)=W(-\log x)/(-\log x)$ coinsides with $h(x)$ at $[e^{-e},e^{1/e}]$, but $g(x)$ is defined in all $x\neq 1$.

Comment: I did something similar here trying to find the area under h(x) instead from 0 to $e^{1/e}$. I am very close to finding the answer, but I kind of had a similar problem as you with as the interval of convergence of the series I used failed to find the full area. [Problem here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168572/integral-over-domain-of-infinite-tetration-of-x-over-its-real-domain-from-0-to)

Comment: Nice! I will check this soon enough. You can simplify by using the [regularized gamma function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/GammaRegularized/). Please evaluate the final answer with M=$\infty$. Thanks. You will see you get the same result I did with a limit unfortunately as you will have to make the second argument of the incomplete gamma function be: -$\infty$k.

Comment: Yes I see the formula it is the same as yours. Also writing (2) with $M$ and not $\infty$ gives more information to the problem. I will search the problem more. However this formula does not apear in Wikipedia.

Comment: Correct, it does give more information, but you can also simplify the gamma function if you like. Thanks for keeping your word that you will edit your nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

From : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function
$$\text{Closed form : }\quad\int_0^\infty x^{-x}dx=\text{Sphd}(-1;\infty)$$
$$\text{Numerical value : Eq.(8:3).}$$

Before downvoting, please read "A schoolboy joke" pp.2-3 in the above referenced paper.

Comment: Of course my "answer" is more a joke that an academic answer since the Sphd function is not a standardized special function and  it's clear this will not happen soon.

Comment: I see you and Claude Leibovici both love jokes. Any other ideas on how to find a form not as an integral? It does not have to be a closed form, just evaluation of  the antiderivative.

Comment: Wait, you wrote this article on Scribd?

Comment: Right. On Scribd : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function .

Comment: Wait isn’t the area under $exp(-x)$ over the positive reals just 1, and not  1.995…?

Comment: Can you maybe please modify the answer so that it has a slightly nicer form that any of my derived ones? Since you came up with the entire sophomore dream function, you should be able to find a nicer form. Please make it without any integral symbol. Perhaps without any limit. The nth derivative for a Taylor Series also looks easy to do. Thanks again!

Comment: The typo is corrected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126761/discussion-between-tyma-gaidash-and-jjacquelin).

Comment: Hi Jean ! Our reputation is now well known ! Cheers.

Comment: Andrew Hendrickson commented about getting Claude “in here”. That comment has now been deleted hence “$exp$“ instead of exp.