# How to calculate the integral of $x^{-x}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

So, I know the integral of $\frac{1}{x^x}$ has not an elementary anti-derivative..

The question is to prove that:
The definite Integral of $x^{-x}$ from $0$ to $1$ equals $$\frac{1}{1^1} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{4^4} +...$$

This problem is an exercise at a book I have bought in the chapter of “definite integrals, improper integrals and integration of series”

Since the requested solution is given in the form of a series, I guess sb has to work by transforming $x^{-x}$ as a series (that’s how the writer solved a similar example) but this requires finding a series which converges at this function..

Any type of help would be appreciated thanks in advance!

Comment: This called the “Sophomore’s dream” integral. Worth looking that up.

Comment: Haha yeah. Just changed that. I though the sophomore dream had a different sign on the exponent but looked it up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237513/series-as-an-integral-sophomores-dream).

Comment: Haha noway. I googled it and I saw freshman’s and sophomore’s dream. Too good to be true haha. I love maths even more after that.

Comment: "I thought the sophomore dream had a different sign on the exponent" [It can refer to either or the pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream), whereas the Freshman's dream [is very different indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream).