# Integral of $x^{-x}$ from $0$ to $1$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I know that we should change this into taylor series form and integrate, but I don't know how exactly it is done. Can someone show me the precise steps that are taken?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/237513/42969

Comment: Why do you think it should be done with a Taylor series? Also, a Taylor series in what? @MartinR's links show how to do it with a Taylor series of sorts, but in $x\ln x$, not $x$.