# How to compute $\sum^ {\infty} _{n=1} {\frac{1}{n^n}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Closed” form for $\sum \frac{1}{n^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/closed-form-for-sum-frac1nn)

\begin{equation}
\sum^ {\infty} _{n=1} {\frac{1}{n^n}}
\end{equation}

I have tried a lot, but can't find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream)

Comment: $$\sum^ {\infty} _{n=1} {\frac{1}{n^n}}=\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x^x} dx$$

Comment: Haha... ‘Dream [it](http://www.levihobbs.com/sophomores-dream/)’ sounds good too.

Comment: Ahhh this brings back memories.

Comment: Is this the answer? The left hand side looks as solved to me as the right hand side.

Comment: I agree with @Fabian: how is the LHS more "computed" after it is written as the RHS, than before? And what does "compute" mean here?

Comment: I thought the series converge to certain number like $\frac{{\pi}^2}{6}$ before asking a question.

Comment: @YongRyu Certainly the value is less than that.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why @Arjang suggested deleting the link to the duplicate question, and why Henry and Brett approved it? I understand these suggested edits less and less every day.

Comment: @RahulNarain : I did not suggest deleting the link, the title was too broad and I made it specific. I just rolled back the role back that was making the title too generic.

Comment: @Arjang: When you roll back to an older version, you remove all the changes that have happened since, including in this case the insertion of the "Possible Duplicate:" link.

Comment: @RahulNarain : Apologies in that case, the version I submitted was rolled back and I failed to notice the other changes, duely noted