# What is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is there any way to express
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^k}.$$
without a sum? I know this converges to ≈ 1,2913 by calculating it, by how can you express this another way? Also, is this number transcendental?

Comment: Very related to ["Closed" form for $\sum \frac{1}{n^n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/).

Comment: Are you interested in this problem from pure curiosity, or do you have a specific reason for wanting to know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another way: [Sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).

(From a computational point of view, this may be no more useful than the sum.)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the integral

> $$ \int_{0}^{1} x^{-x} dx . $$