# Convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^k}$ through Cauchy criterion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So I need to show that the series $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^k}$$ converges, which is very quick using different tests, but the caveat is that I need to do this using the Cauchy criterion for series. This boils down to showing the sequence of partial sums $(s_n)$ is Cauchy, but the problem lies in actually finding a closed form for $(s_n)$.

I tried checking by hand the cases $n=1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ to find a pattern, make an educated guess and prove it correct by induction, but no clear pattern arises.

Comment: There is no closed form. See also [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1687783p10779394), or [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454812/what-is-sum-k-1-infty-frac1kk?noredirect=1).

Comment: So... you don't need to find a closed form for the partial sums themselves, just estimates that satisfy the Cauchy criterion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Closed" form for $\sum \frac{1}{n^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/closed-form-for-sum-frac1nn)

Comment: For $k\ge 2$, the series converges faster than the series $\sum_{k\ge 2}\frac1{k^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Cauchy criterion applied to the partial sums $(s_n)$, given $\varepsilon > 0$, we need to find some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $m \geq n \geq N$,
$$
|s_m - s_n| = \Biggl|\, \sum_{n < k \leq m}\!\! a_k \,\Biggr| < \varepsilon.
$$

As long as you can find some other series $(b_n)$ such that
$$
0 < a_n \leq b_n 
$$
and the series $\displaystyle\sum_{1 \leq n} b_n$ is Cauchy, you're good. *Try to find such a series before revealing the spoiler.*

> In your series, the summands are $a_n = n^{-n} \leq 2^{-n}$ for any $n \geq 2$, and $$\begin{align} \sum_{n < k \leq m}\!\! k^{-k} &\leq \sum_{n < k \leq m}\!\! 2^{-k} \\ &= \sum_{0 < k \leq m}\!\! 2^{-k} - \sum_{0 < k \leq n}\!\! 2^{-k} \\ &= \frac12 \cdot \frac{1 - 2^{-m}}{1 - 2^{-1}} - \frac12 \cdot \frac{1 - 2^{-n}}{1 - 2^{-1}} \\ &= \bigl( 1 - 2^{-m} \bigr) - \bigl( 1 - 2^{-n} \bigr) \\ &= 2^{-n} -  2^{-m} \\ &\leq 2^{-n}, \end{align}$$ so choosing $N > -\frac{\ln\varepsilon}{\ln 2}$ suffices to yield $2^{-n} \leq 2^{-N} < \varepsilon$.

Comment: I originally tried this using a geometric series, but the details became too laborious for me. Nicely done!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $s(n)=\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-k}$. Cauchy's criterion requires that we show that , for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $N\in\Bbb N$ such that

$$|s(n+m)-s(n)|\leq \epsilon \\ m\in\mathbb N$$
For all $n> N$.

In our case,
$$|s(n+m)-s(n)|=\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+m}k^{-k}=\sum_{k=1}^m (n+k)^{-(n+k)}$$
We know, for certain, that
$$|s(n+m)-s(n)|\leq \sum_{k=1}^m (n+k)^{-2}$$
By simply comparing terms.

We can bound this sum with an integral (draw a graph!)
$$\sum_{k=1}^m (n+k)^{-2}\leq \int_1^m \frac{1}{(n+x-1)^2}\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+m-1}\leq \frac{1}{n}$$
Therefore
$$|s(n+m)-s(n)|\leq \frac{1}{n}$$

Therefore, for any given $\epsilon$, we can simply choose an $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$. $\blacksquare$