# Is there any closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^k}$?

Tags: summation, closed-form

Is there any closed form for the summation:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^k} = ? $$
or at least a tight lower bound?

Comment: An upper bound is $e$.  Also see http://oeis.org/A073009

Comment: There are several question about the infinite sum, like [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/closed-form-for-sum-frac1nn) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/21330).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

J. Bernoulli showed that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}= \int_0^1 x^{-x}\,dx$$

This result is often called the "[Sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)" because it looks too good to be true.

I don't believe there is a form more "closed" than this.

Comment: Do you think there is a closed form lower bound?

Comment: @majid.khonji I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but for $n>1$, the sum trivially is $>1$.

Comment: You are right. In fact, I am looking for an answer for another question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478516/any-tight-lower-bound-for-this-expression