# Help with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n+1)^n}{n^{2n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Not sure how to really get started with this because it seems like a geometric series.  Can some provide me a hint as to how I should approach this series?  I started to use the ratio test but quickly noticed the difficulty I'd have with simplifying it algebraically.

Is the ratio test the only test I can use?

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n+1)^n}{n^{2n}}$

Comment: Are you familiar with the root test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$u_n=\frac{(2n+1)^n}{n^{2n}}=\left(\frac{2n+1}{n^2}\right)^n$$
then by the Cauchy test we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(u_n)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n^2}=0<1$$
so the series is convergent.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Cauchy test... but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use limit comparison test by comparing against
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac3{n^n}$$
Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/closed-form-for-sum-frac1nn) for more info on $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n^n}$.