# Computing $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^k}$ analytically

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

The series
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^k}$$
clearly converges. Is it possible to compute its value analytically?

Comment: This is Sophomore's Dream. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/closed-form-for-sum-frac1nn:

Comment: Since such series equals $\int_{0}^{1}\exp\left(-x\log x\right)\,dx$, its numerical value turns out to be pretty close to $$ \exp\int_{0}^{1}-x\log(x)\,dx = e^{1/4},$$ by Jensen's inequality.

Comment: That is an interesting estimate, thanks!