# What is the exact value of $\sum\limits_{x=1}^∞\frac1{x^x}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

On the internet I found an evaluation of the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{-x} \,\mathrm{d}x$ which results in $$\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^x}.$$
Seeing this graphically I found that the sum does seem to converge to approximately $1.291$. So as it converges shouldn't we be able to find its exact value? Can someone please tell me what this value is or how I may be able to find it?

Edit:

While searching about this I came across [Sophomore's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/closed-form-for-sum-frac1nn?rq=1) which is quite interesting but none of them can quite give a closed value (in terms of known constants like $\pi$, $\phi$ or *e*). So does $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^x} $ or $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{-x} \,\mathrm{d}x$ not have such a value? Is it irrational? So many questions.

Comment: The series you wrote seems to be missing an $n$ somewhere.

Comment: Is this meant to be $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^n}}$?

Comment: Yes, extremely sorry about that.

Comment: There is no known "closed form" of the type you ask about.

Comment: See https://www.scribd.com/document/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most you can say/prove is that the integral and the series are equal (easy to prove), and that the integral has no elementary anti-derivative (hard to prove, but there's one if you know some Galois theory). There's no known closed form for this value. It's not known whether it's rational/irrational.